# Firefox completely ignores click event

Tags: javascript, events, firefox

In code below when JS is busy looping and I click the document it seems that Firefox completely ignores it. It should register click and execute it after the current JS thread is finished but the alert from click callback never shows. Why is that? This happens in Firefox only, Chrome seems fine. Fiddle is in here http://jsfiddle.net/QQjya/7/

```
function homerSays() {
    alert("hmm.. Doghnuts...");
}

setTimeout(homerSays, 5000);

document.onclick = function () {
    alert("DOH!");
}

for (i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    box.innerHTML = i;
}
```

Comment: Maybe the listener is not live until the JS "thread" finished? Why would it need to? Anyway, what difference does it make - you hardly need such behaviour, do you?

Comment: trying to understand workings of task queues and this doesn't make much sense it seems. The click, even when JS is currently running should be put into one of task queues and executed sooner or later, at least I thought it should

Comment: Yes, but only if the task queue is configured to catch clicks - which it might not yet be. Try to put the loop into the `homerSays` timeout and it should work.

Comment: not sure what you mean by "configured to catch clicks"? got any links that would explain it in a bit more details or would you mind explaining a bit more? Cheers,

Comment: Basically I mean that the listener is set up. If there are no listeners, the task queue won't store the events. And maybe the actual listener setup (registering at the task queue) is deferred until the "thread" ends, so that FF won't catch events that are fired during the same event loop turn as the `addEventListener`.